# Adding a new separate menu link to /admin/config in page?

Tags: 8

Adding new separate menu link in admin config page  like development service

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Adding link to admin config under development, media, service is easy but creating new separate menu like admin_config_development, admin_config_service , admin_config_media is bit tricky.

As mentioned in

> Create same file with small alteration  **modulename.links.menu.yml**
>
> ```
> modulename.admin_config_modulename:
>   title: ' settings'
>   description: ' selection.'
>   route_name: modulename.settings
>   parent: 'system.admin_config'
> modulename.second_link:
>   title: 'settings'
>   description: 'selection.'
>   route_name: modulename.settinganother
>   parent: 'modulename.admin_config_modulename'  
>   menu_name: modulename
> ```
>
> <sup>By: monkpal</sup>

Comment: I modified your answer as link only answers are not acceptable here. Why? because if the website you're linking goes down, your answer is useless. I have quoted the relevant part and gave credit to the author.